# How can I create a vocabulary of words for this seq2seq implementation?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I followed a tutorial for a seq2seq model.

I did everything, <strike>although the guy uses an unknown</strike> and this is the [helper.py](https://github.com/llSourcell/seq2seq_model_live/blob/master/helpers.py) module that generates random sentences (ex. `[6, 5, 9, 4]`).

Now, if I understand correctly, seq2seq models transform words into numbers by placing them in a vocabulary, assigning them an index (I am not too sure about it being an index but it's something similar) and then using those numbers to represent the word.

He uses this code:

```
batch_size = 100

batches = helpers.random_sequences(length_from=3, length_to=8,
                               vocab_lower=2, vocab_upper=10,
                               batch_size=batch_size)
```

and this:

```
def next_feed():
    batch = next(batches)
    encoder_inputs_, encoder_input_lengths_ = helpers.batch(batch)
    decoder_targets_, _ = helpers.batch(
        [(sequence) + [EOS] + [PAD] * 2 for sequence in batch]
    )
    return {
        encoder_inputs: encoder_inputs_,
        encoder_inputs_length: encoder_input_lengths_,
        decoder_targets: decoder_targets_,
    }
```

How could I write a vocabulary that I can use with this?

EDIT: To give more context, this is what he wrote:

> **Training on the toy task**
>
> Consider the copy task — given a random sequence of integers from a vocabulary, learn to memorize and reproduce input sequence. Because sequences are random, they do not contain any structure, unlike natural language.

(Then he shows the code that's in the post)

Comment: We can't tell; the code you posted says nothing about the lexicon format.  You'll have to refer to the original documentation for the `seq2seq` implementation you're using.  In most cases, there is a data ingestion method that takes an input file in a particular format.  You need to find that particular format.

Comment: That's the thing. There IS no lexicon format. The only thing that I know is that there is an helper module that generates 'batches' (which I assume are sentences).

Comment: Just to clarify: there *has* to be a format; what we're missing is the *specification* of that format.

Comment: Yes, these "batches" are the randomly generated sentences.

Comment: We can't help at this point -- the format information appears to be encapsulated within the `helpers` object of class `helper`, on which you've given us no information.  It's also possible that `helper` uses only the internal lexicon (the sequence of integers), and the actual words are hidden in another package.  Since we know nothing about your tutorial, there's no way we can hunt for that module.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand what do you mean by format. Regardless, [here](https://github.com/llSourcell/seq2seq_model_live/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb) is what I've followed. Alright, sorry I am dumb and didn't check the full github project. There is an helper module.

Comment: "Format" would be the input specification for the dictionary, or it could be the internal representation used as reference for sentence generation.

Comment: Please edit critical information into your question.  I put your `here` link in place in the first sentence of your post.

Comment: Note the top of this page, where it discusses the encoder and decoder.  These are interfaces the model uses.  You're asking to get into the data stream before this point, so you'll need to dig back to see where the encoder gets its dictionary, and then to see how you can affect that dictionary.

Comment: The vocabulary part is on the very bottom. I checked helper.py although I can't seem to find the input specification you are talking about.

Comment: Ah -- I see -- `helpers` appears to be a separate module, independent of any class.  Dead end -- I would think that the next line of attack would be to dig into and past the `encoder` to see how the data flows there.

Comment: Alright, will do! Will post tomorrow about it.

Comment: Excellent.  Yes, you're stuck with trying to "dive under the hood", to use the auto mechanic's term.